# Rewrite rule not working - Redirect to new url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

we moved to the new cms, there are links that need to be redirected from the old url to the new ones, wrote the revrite rule, but nothing works, in what

Old url - site.com/1222_titlepost.html
New url - site.com/blog/{slug} - id

> RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]{1,})_([0-9a-z]{1,}).html blog/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Centos 7 , apache2 , php7 , whm+cpanel

Comment: I doubt that the new URL actually should contain blancs... Could you please provide two _real_ examples of old and new URL? Thanks.

Comment: OLD Random url - site.com/post/194_myfirst_post.html
New url - site.com/blog/194

Answer (score 0):

The example you give in the comment to the question does *not* match what you claimed in the question. If *that* really expresses the actual task, then the answer to your question is pretty simple:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?post/(\d+)_ /blog/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: this is my htacess 
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/?post/(\d+)_ /blog/$1 [R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Did you make sure that the dynamic configuration file is considered and interpreted _at all_ by your http server? How did you do that? And "not working" means what _exactly_ ? What does your http servers error log file reveal?